# Hello? Where is the WebRTC feature in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I recently upgraded Firefox to version 34, expecting to see the new Hello WebRTC feature that I read about on [OMG! Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/12/firefox-34-changes-include-hello-html5-webide) as well as [Firefox Hello - video and voice conversations online](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-hello-make-receive-calls-without-account) and 
[Firefox Hello: voice and video calls without account requirement](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/10/17/firefox-hello-voice-and-video-calls-without-account-requirement/)
.

However, when going into customization mode, I do not see the speech bubble icon. What am I missing? Is it not included in the release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that Mozilla his disabled this for most users. You need to go to `about:config` and set `loop.throttled` to `false`.

More info here: http://techdows.com/2014/12/fix-no-hello-button-in-firefox-34.html

From the above article:

> Reason: Mozilla has intentionally not enabled the button for users,
>   they’re not confident of their servers taking the load when users use
>   this feature, that’s why they’ve set the throttling to 10%.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Firefox, WebRTC is enabled by default.
However WebRTC cannot be found in the user interface of Firefox directly, because WebRTC is basically a feature [**which is built in into many browsers**](http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com).

However Mozilla has built its own system and user interface around it so you can use it in Firefox with a few clicks.
Just click on the button with a smiley included in a speech bubble:

> [image]

Besides this, Mozilla's website currently has a **summary of the features** of WebRTC and a big button you can click on to start a conversation, located: https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/hello/

Here is the **support article link**: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-hello-video-and-voice-conversations-online